# python -list -function question take list with function

Tags: python, list, function

My goal is to create a function that finds all the files of a specific type (extension) in a folder and places them in a list.
As arguments of the function I set:

1. file type (.xlsx, .png, .txt)
2. the list name where the files will be placed

I was able to find all the files of a specific type.
I was able to see the files in a list on my terminal
I was NOT able to put the files in a list with the name of my choice so that later during the execution I can call the specific list with the name of my choice or any name.
Could someone help me solve the problem?
thanks in advance for understanding.

```
def find_all_filles_courrent_dir(type,namelist):
      # Η συνάρτηση βρίσκει όλα τα αρχεία τύπου type και τα τοποθετεί σε λίστα με όνομα namelist
    import glob
    x=str("*")+str(".")+str(type)
    namelist = [f for f in glob.glob(x)]
    
    print("Λίστα με τα αρχεία στον υπάρχον φάκελο είναι:",namelist)

    
find_all_filles_courrent_dir("xlsx","listafor")
print(listafor)

when I run :

> python3 try2.py
Λίστα με τα αρχεία στον υπάρχον φάκελο είναι: ['democreate.xlsx', 'test3.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx', 'test5.xlsx', 'test4.xlsx', 'test1.xlsx', 'teststable.xlsx']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try2.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(listafor)
NameError: name 'listafor' is not defined
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. But it *seems* like you have a fundamental misunderstanding how how functions work. Your function doesn't do anything with your list except print it, then returns nothing. You shouldn't try to dynamically create variables. Your function should *return the list* then do something like `my_var = find_all_files_current_dir('xlsx')` Note, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, because that is used for the built-in `list` type

Comment: please take a look again...i re-edit ...
How can take all filles in one list?
how can take the names as a object and put them in a list?
thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```py
def find_all_filles_courrent_dir(type,namelist):
      # Η συνάρτηση βρίσκει όλα τα αρχεία τύπου type και τα τοποθετεί σε λίστα με όνομα namelist
    import glob
    x=str("*")+str(".")+str(type)
    globals()[namelist] = [f for f in glob.glob(x)]
    
    print("Λίστα με τα αρχεία στον υπάρχον φάκελο είναι:",namelist)

    
find_all_filles_courrent_dir("xlsx","listafor")
print(listafor)
```